# Reading from file raises IndexError in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am making an app which will return one random line from the `.txt` file. I made a class to implement this behaviour. The idea was to use one method to open file (which will remain open) and the other method which will close it after the app exits. I do not have much experience in working with files hence the following behaviour is strange to me:

In `__init__` I called `self.open_file()` in order to just open it. And it works fine to get `self.len`. Now I thought that I do not need to call `self.open_file()` again, but when I call `file.get_term()`(returns random line) it raises `IndexError` (like the file is empty), But, if I call `file.open_file()` method again, everything works as expected.

In addition to this `close_file()` method raises `AttributeError` - `object has no attribute 'close'`, so I assumed the file closes automatically somehow, even if I did not use `with open`.

```
import random
import os


class Pictionary_file:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.open_file()
        self.len = self.get_number_of_lines()

    def open_file(self):
        self.opened = open(self.file, "r", encoding="utf8")

    def get_number_of_lines(self):
        i = -1
        for i, line in enumerate(self.opened):
            pass
        return i + 1

    def get_term_index(self):
        term_line = random.randint(0, self.len-1)
        return term_line

    def get_term(self):
        term_line = self.get_term_index()
        term = self.opened.read().splitlines()[term_line]

    def close_file(self):
        self.opened.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(os.getcwd())
    file = Pictionary_file("pictionary.txt")
    file.open_file()                            #WITHOUT THIS -> IndexError
    file.get_term()
    file.close()                            #AttributeError
```

Where is my mistake and how can I correct it?

Comment: File objects are stream-like. Reading from the advanced advanced the position in the stream – reading them completely means the position is at the *end* of the stream, and more more data is available. See [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) for details.

Comment: I see, I added `seek(0)` and it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in `__init__`:

```
self.open_file()
self.len = self.get_number_of_lines()
```

`self.get_number_of_lines()` actually consumes the whole file because it iterates over it:

```
def get_number_of_lines(self):
    i = -1
    for i, line in enumerate(self.opened):
        # real all lines of the file
        pass
    # at this point, `self.opened` is empty
    return i + 1
```

So when `get_term` calls `self.opened.read()`, it gets an empty string, so `self.opened.read().splitlines()` is an empty list.

`file.close()` is an `AttributeError`, because the `Pictionary_file` class doesn't have the `close` method. It does have `close_file`, though.

Comment: I learnt the first part from the previous comment, but additional explanation is very useful. About the closing file part I can't believe I made this mistake. Thank you for answering